# Splash screen is stretching in Nexus 4

Tags: android, screen, splash-screen, nexus-4

I pasted my code below: problem is the image is stretching......

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use 9 page image . You can generate 9-patch images from [9-path generator.](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html).

after that modify your imageView like as

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Problem solved for me.I changed scaleType to metrix.

Answer (score 0):

Use wrap_content instead of match_parent:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Problem solved for me.I changed scaleType to metrix.